# How to get username of currently logged in user of a remote computer through website, while your webserver is on the same network?

Tags: c#, networking, proxy, network-programming

I know many of you will think that my questions been already asked and answered but i just want to discuss many options i have tried.

Now my setup is this.
some 50 clients running windows xp professional.
One server running windows server 2003. call it server A
One server running squid as proxy server and linux OS . call it server B
One server running Apache ( though wamp server ). call it server C.
now clients login to domain using windows active directory and the domain server is server A.
now the browsers are configured to use proxy server which is server B.

Proxy server's been configured to not allow downloads greater than a limit ( i.e. 100 Mb in my case ). and when client makes a request exceeding the limit, user is shown an error page.

Now I Have replaced the error page and it redirects the user to my website which is running on machine C. I am also given the link user was trying to access. Now what I need to find out which user was logged on into the system. so i can download the file and then notify the respective user of the downloads completion.

Now what I could have done is simply asked for the users name or email etc...
but i want to save user from the hustle of entering his name again.

I have tried following options.

1. .NET http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/getusername.aspx ( didnt work.
   may be i missed something )
2. wmic http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntadmincommands.php#Cmd02 ( worked )
3. authetication through squid ( ldap, active directory etc )

now I have questions regarding this.

1. Are these all options i have or am i missing something ?
2. why didnt the .NET option work ?
3. I can use any of the various squid authentication methods but i guess all will need the user to log in at least once after the log onto computer. I dont want this. is there a way I can just use the authentication done when user loged in adn not ask him for user name and password again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the user's domain login, within an ASP.Net application, you need to use `Request.ServerVariables("logon_user")`.

However, there are also other considerations:

1) You must only have Windows Authentication enabled for the web site.

2) Your user's browsers (assuming IE) must have `Enable Integrated Windows Authentication` turned on.

3) If the request from the browser to your ASP.Net application is indirect (i.e. more than 1 hop), then you will have to ensure that all of the systems involved are configured for Kerberos authentication (which can be very "challenging").

You could also setup ASP.Net to [impersonate the end user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28VS.71%29.aspx), which would allow your original code to work correctly. However, this means that everything that happens in the thread (database access, file access, etc) will be performed as the end user.

Comment: Thankyou for your responce. just to be clear.
this will give me the username of currenly logged in user who accessed my website.

I used
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
to get the username of the client.

when i opened the website on the same machine on which IIS was running i got the username of current logged in user. but when i accessed the site in another pc the username was something else.

Comment: The GetCurrent().Name will give you the name of the thread executor; if you have identity impersonation turned on then it "could" be the end user. If you don't, then it will be the ASP.Net Application Pool identity.